# Look for multiple characters using string.gsbu

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I would like to use `string.gsub` to search through a phone number field and remove any "-" or spaces.

Is there any way to combine the two statements I have below into one?

```
local phonenumber = string.gsub("123-123-1234", "-", "")
phonenumber = string.gsub(phonenumber , " ", "")
```

Comment: `phonenumber = phonenumber:gsub('%D', '')`

Comment: Many commercial and public service phone numbers are written in letters (in the U.S., at least) so they are easier to remember. Also, phone numbers can be suffixed with extensions separated by 'x'. `:gsub('%D', '')` would cause data loss.

Comment: @TomBlodget he only gave one input example, so i'd be highly surprised if he's looking for a robust solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. 
The square brackets are used to group multiple elements in Lua patterns

```
local phonenumber = string.gsub("123-123 -1234", "[- ]", "")
```